# How to analyze a large heapdump?

Tags: java, heap-dump

Is there a tool to analyze a large Java Heap dump (2GB), if one only can assign 1,5GB to the JVM? I can't believe the dump must be fully loaded into memory to be analyzed...

Eclipse MemoryAnalyzer fails, and the IBM tool also.

Do I need to use command line tools here now?

Comment: Use a 64bit VM on a 64bit OS and give it enough memory. There's no other way that I know.

Comment: YourKit is good at handling large dumps. I have used it with 8 GB dumps, but on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: How can the heap dump get that big on a 32-bit JVM? Is it the extra non-heap allocation?

Comment: @artbristol: The dump was created on a 64bit server VM, but my dev PC is 32bit.

Comment: I have found in the past that a Linux disk can be your friend. No need to install the OS, just boot the OS from CD and have a Linux copy of MAT (Eclipse Memory Analyzer) sitting somewhere on your hard drive. Then you can analyze the dump file through that.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254017/tool-for-analyzing-large-java-heap-dumps

Answer (score 3):

If it's a dev server, restrict the max heap size to something a 32-bit OS can handle. If it's in production, demand a 64-bit OS! If you can't get that, you can run jhat on the server (it has a web interface you can access on your own PC).

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to install the `MAT tool` on the remote server and generate an HTML output of the analysis to download and view locally.  This saves the headache of attempting to get X Windows installed on the remote machine and get all of the `ssh` tunneling sorted out (which is of course an option as well).

First, download and install the stand-alone Eclipse RCP Application.  Then transfer to your server and unpack.  Then determine how large the heap dump is and, if necessary, modify the **MemoryAnalyzer.in**i file to instantiate a JVM with enough RAM for your heap dump.

In this example, I have an 11GB heap dump and have modified the last two lines (adding -Xms)

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-vmargs
-Xmx16g
-Xms16g
```

Do an initial run to parse the heap dump.  This will generate intermediary data that can be used by subsequent runs to make future analysis faster.

```
./ParseHeapDump.sh /path/to/heap-dump
```

After that completes, you can run any of a number of different analysis on the data.  The following is an illustration of how to search for memory leak suspects.

```
./ParseHeapDump.sh /path/to/heap-dump org.eclipse.mat.api:suspec
```

Comment: Nice info... will try this the next time!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Eclipse MAT and all heap dump analysis tools loads entire heap dump into memory in order to do the analysis. If Eclipse MAT fails for you, you may try [HeapHero](https://heaphero.io/) tool. JHAT take lore more memory and time than Eclipse MAT to analyze heap dumps.